# Help to solving this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I have this equation:

$$ \frac{d^2R}{d\rho^2}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{dR}{d\rho}+\left(\frac{d}{\rho}+k^2-\frac{m^2}{\rho^2}\right)R=0 $$

Where R is a function of $\rho$ $(R(\rho))$

d,k and m are constant.

I put this in maple and the solution is terms of whittaker function but I don't how to work with that function, so there is a way to express this equation in other form, to get a more easily equation to work with?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maple has a "series" option, if you'd rather work with a series solution.

Comment: ... in which case you should note that $0$ is a regular singular point with indicial roots $\pm m$; if $m$ is an integer or half-integer, there will be logarithmic terms.

Comment: Where is your try in maple?

Answer (score 0):

The equation is
$$r^{2}R''+rR'+(dr^{2}+k^{2}r-m^{2})R=0$$
Do the substitution
$$R=r^{{m}}f(r)$$
You get
$$rf''+(2m+1)f'+(dr+k^{2})f=0$$
Then do the substitution
$$f=e^{i\sqrt{b}r}g(r)$$
you get the confluent hypergeometric equation
$$rg''+(2i\sqrt{b}r+2m+1)g'+(k^{2}+(2m+1)i\sqrt{b})g=0$$
This have 2 independent solutions
$$g_{1}=e^{-2i\sqrt{b}r}U\Big(m+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{k^{2}}{2i\sqrt{b}}, 2m+1; 2i\sqrt{b}r\Big)$$
and
$$g_{2}=e^{-2i\sqrt{b}r}L^{2m}_{\frac{k^{2}}{2i\sqrt{b}}-m-\frac{1}{2}}(2i\sqrt{b}r)$$
Where U(., .; z) is the confluent hypergeometric fucntion of the second kind and $L^{.}_{.}(z)$ is the assosiated Laggure polynomial. The second solution is singular unless
$$\Big(\frac{k^{2}}{2i\sqrt{b}}-m-\frac{1}{2}\Big)\in\mathbb{N}$$